# How do you Prevent Window from showing old contents when SW_HIDE then SW_SHOWNORMAL?

Tags: winapi, gdi

I am finding if you have a `WS_POPUP` Window or Dialog and draw in it, then you `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)` it, change what you're drawing in it (even make a call to draw on the DC), do a `ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL)` it will flash the old contents before drawing the new contents.  It seems Windows caches the data someplace so that `ShowWindow` shows it quick (with old contents), how do I prevent `ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL)` from showing the prior contents? I tried `InvalidateRect()` already, no difference.   I only get it when hiding then showing (which I'd rather do then destroying and creating the window each time it's needed).

Update:

Appears to be related to:

```
  LONG ExtendedStyle = GetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE);
  SetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE, ExtendedStyle | WS_EX_LAYERED);
  ::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(GetSafeHwnd(), RGB(1, 11, 21), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Thanks.

Comment: After calling `ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL)`, the window will be redrawn, and finally `WM_PAINT` will be called repeatedly. It’s better minimize your code to the Max and show it us.

Comment: How is it redrawn?  How do I stop it from redrawing and just move on to WM_PAINT?

Comment: Before answering these questions, I would like to know what is your purpose after you hide the window, draw the window and then restore it?

Comment: Say user selects a graphic to view and interact with, say draw some stuff on it, when done hide window, next item select what is to be drawn in window, unhide it, shows new items (but problem is seems the prior data was cached and draw back to screen when shown, then the new content ends up drawing).  I could delete dialog/window and create again, but wonder what's going on here and how to stop it.

Comment: A hidden window will not generate `WM_PAINT` messages. It's unclear how you *"draw in it"*, since rendering a window's contents is to be performed in `WM_PAINT` and `WM_PAINT` only. But sure, the system will cache the window's contents. How else would features like Aero Peek work.

Comment: I did not reproduce your problem. Please add some code and screenshots to the question.

Comment: Couldn't get it to happen in test app either, then found the layered style was set, add to test add and saw same issue.  The weird thing is I removed it from the main app and it was still doing it.  Add the layered lines I found to original question that were in the "OnCreate" for the window.

Comment: I will assume this is a caveat to how layered windows are cached/drawn to. When you set the layered attribute on a window, everything with the window changes. It won't act like a normal window any more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows

Comment: call [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows). After the call, the system may still ask the window to paint when the window is shown or resized. However, because the system stores the image of a layered window, the system will not ask the window to paint if parts of it are revealed as a result of relative window moves on the desktop.  In addition, using UpdateLayeredWindow directly uses memory more efficiently, because the system does not need the additional memory required for storing the image of the redirected window